# Scala UDF does not match null in pattern matching

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

While pattern matching in Scala UDF, which is matching pattern for a column with double datatype, it is unable to capture records with null values in it

```
  val Binning = udf((colValue: Double) => {
    colValue match {
      case 1 => "one_day"
      case x if (x > 1 && x <= 4) => "two_to_four_days"
      case x if (x > 4 && x <= 7) => "four_to_seven_days"
      case x if (x > 7 && x <= 14) => "one_to_two_weeks"
      case x if (x > 14 && x <= 31) => "two_to_four_weeks"
      case x if (x > 31 && x <= 90) => "more_than_one_month"
      case x if (x > 90) => "more_than_three_month"
      case _ => "zero_days"
    }
```

in output i am getting:

```
+--------------------+
|          output    |
+--------------------+
|more_than_three_m...|
| more_than_one_month|
|   two_to_four_weeks|
|    one_to_two_weeks|
|    two_to_four_days|
|           zero_days|
|  four_to_seven_days|
|                null|
|             one_day|
+--------------------+
```

it should not be filling null in output. Any idea what is going worng?

Comment: can you try using the `na.fill(REPLACEMENT_VALUE_FOR_NULL)`